# Was it mandatory to put a "distinct" field as the first field in a query?

Tags: sqlite

Just out of curiosity, looks like a `distinct` field must be placed ahead of any other fields, am I wrong?

See this example in SQLite,

```
sqlite> select ip, distinct code from parser; # syntax error?
Error: near "distinct": syntax error
sqlite> select distinct code, ip from parser; # works
```

Why is that? Do I really have a syntax error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**There is no such thing as a "`distinct` field".**

`distinct` applies to all fields in the query and therefore must appear immediately after `select`.

In other words, `select distinct code, ip` is really

```
select distinct
code,
ip
```

rather than

```
select
distinct code,
ip
```

It selects all distinct pairs of `(code, ip)`. Thus the result set could include repeated values of `code` (each with a different value of `ip`).

It is not possible to apply `distinct` to a single field in the way you're trying to (`group by` might be a useful alternative, but we need to understand what it is exactly that you're trying to achieve).

Comment: Yes, only Postgres (besides the usual `DISTINCT` modifier) has an additional **[`DISTINCT ON (expression)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)** construction.